# angular UI bootstrap datepicker can't get value using JQuery expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using datepicker from angular UI bootstrap lib.
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/Datepicker

after select date, I'm not able to get the text of input using JQuery expression.
    $('#effectiveDate').text()
is always returning empty, but I can see it has value on the page.

What can I do to retrieve this value?

updates:
in chrome console,

$('#effectiveDate') returns:

```
[<input id=​"effectiveDate" name=​"effectiveDate" type=​"text" class=​"form-control pickdaterInput ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-date ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" datepicker-popup=​"dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model=​"elt.registrationState.effectiveDate" is-open=​"opened" min-date=​"minDate" datepicker-options=​"dateOptions" close-text=​"Close">​]
```

$('#effectiveDate').text(); returns;

```
""
```

angular.element($0).scope().elt.registrationState.effectiveDate returns:

```
Tue Jul 14 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

but in Selenium:

```
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String effectiveDate_string = js.executeScript("angular.element($0).scope().elt.registrationState.effectiveDate.getTime().toString()").toString();
```

gives error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: $0 is not defined
(Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.132)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457   (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
```

Comment: i think u can get the value using the ngmodel of your element with $scope.myPickerInput

Comment: Use ng-model see example here http://jsfiddle.net/cletourneau/kGGCZ/

Comment: @Vanojx1   if I run this in chrome, I'm able to retrieve the value of date in million seconds. angular.element($0).scope().elt.registrationState.effectiveDate.getTime().toString()   but when I run this code in selenium         String effectiveDate_string = js.executeScript("angular.element($0).scope().elt.registrationState.effectiveDate.getTime().toString()").toString();
it gives error:org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: $0 is not defined

Comment: cant understand why u re using angular.element method when you can use  the scope value, have you tried that??

Comment: $scope is undefined when I tried to run this in chrome console:   $scope.elt.registrationState.effectiveDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try clicking on the actual input element in Chrome (firefox) and then typing this in the console?

```
 angular.element($0).val()
```

Also, did you try this

```
 $('#effectiveDate').val()
```

instead of this

```
$('#effectiveDate').text()
```

**UPDATE**

regarding the comment

> this is $('#effectiveDate') returns: 
>   [​]

```
$('#effectiveDate')[0].val()
```

The reason is that when you are calling **$('#effectiveDate')** you are getting an array with only one value that you care about, which means you have to get the first item of the array, thus [0]. You may also try this for more readability.

```
$('#effectiveDate').first().val();
```

Comment: $('#effectiveDate').val()  and  $('#effectiveDate').text()  don't work in console.    angular.element($0).val() works in console. but when I using selenium run this:  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String effectiveDate_string = js.executeScript("angular.element($0).scope().elt.registrationState.effectiveDate.getTime().toString()").toString();
 it gives error:  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: $0 is not defined

Comment: First, check and see that $('#effectiveDate') returns an actual DOM element. If it does not, TS why it is not on the page. Perhaps you have an ng-if that isn't creating it when you think it should be there. Let me know what you find when you check for the element.

Comment: this is $('#effectiveDate') returns:
[<input id=​"effectiveDate" name=​"effectiveDate" type=​"text" class=​"form-control pickdaterInput ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-date ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" datepicker-popup=​"dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model=​"elt.registrationState.effectiveDate" is-open=​"opened" min-date=​"minDate" datepicker-options=​"dateOptions" close-text=​"Close">​]

Comment: great! now just call $('#effectiveDate')[0].val().

Comment: would you say this answered your question?

Comment: Yes, I've selected this as answer.